# Cannot Customize using customize browser on portal

Tags: acumatica

I associated a business account for an unrestricted external user and have provided both portal admin and customizer roles but still cannot customize on the portal and when I try to open a customization project, it says

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a case open with Acumatica on the same issue.  The problem is the main project browser page is missing from the portal site map.  **Run the SQL statement below on the database and restart the Acumatica instance.**

UPDATE 6/15/2018 - I ran into this issue again on another upgrade and my original script below didn't work because the Position field was wrong.  I have adjusted it to insert into Position 1036 which now seems to work.

```
INSERT INTO PortalMap (CompanyID, Position, Title, Description, Url, Expanded, IsFolder, ScreenID, CompanyMask, NodeID, ParentID, CreatedByID, CreatedByScreenID, CreatedDateTime, LastModifiedByID, LastModifiedByScreenID, LastModifiedDateTime)
SELECT CompanyID, 1036, Title, Description, Url, Expanded, IsFolder, ScreenID, CompanyMask, NodeID, '84351BC9-BF6C-48B5-9DEA-F8207283B64A', CreatedByID, CreatedByScreenID, CreatedDateTime, LastModifiedByID, LastModifiedByScreenID, LastModifiedDateTime FROM SiteMap WHERE ScreenID = 'AU000000' AND CompanyID = 1
```

Comment: I have this issue after restoring a client's db backup, but this script didn't help.  Anyone solve this differently? I can't modify my customizations.

Comment: I still run the same command when upgrading clients with the portal to 2019.  The biggest thing is restarting the Acumatica application.  Sometimes I restart it from the Apply Updates screen from within the main instance.  I've found restarting the application pool doesn't always take.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Peter Rankin I updated my script the same way and it worked for 2019R1

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PortalMap
(
    CompanyID,
    Position,
    Title,
    Description,
    Url,
    ScreenID,
    CompanyMask,
    NodeID,
    ParentID,
    CreatedByID,
    CreatedByScreenID,
    CreatedDateTime,
    LastModifiedByID,
    LastModifiedByScreenID,
    LastModifiedDateTime,
    RecordSourceID
)
SELECT CompanyID,
       Position,
       Title,
       Description,
       Url,
       ScreenID,
       CompanyMask,
       NodeID,
       ParentID,
       CreatedByID,
       CreatedByScreenID,
       CreatedDateTime,
       LastModifiedByID,
       LastModifiedByScreenID,
       LastModifiedDateTime,
       RecordSourceID
FROM dbo.SiteMap
WHERE ScreenID Like 'AU%'
      AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.PortalMap
    WHERE CompanyID = dbo.SiteMap.CompanyID
          AND ScreenID = dbo.SiteMap.ScreenID
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am on 2020 R1 and had an issue with [JvD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6225129/jvd)'s solution. After running his script, I was able to open the customization browser, however the left-hand panel was blank which severely limits the browser's functionality. I noticed there were more missing rows for AU pages in the PortalMap than just AU000000 so I modified the script to pull all missing AU sites from SiteMap into PortalMap, which resolved my issue.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PortalMap
(
    CompanyID,
    Position,
    Title,
    Description,
    Url,
    ScreenID,
    CompanyMask,
    NodeID,
    ParentID,
    CreatedByID,
    CreatedByScreenID,
    CreatedDateTime,
    LastModifiedByID,
    LastModifiedByScreenID,
    LastModifiedDateTime,
    RecordSourceID
)
SELECT CompanyID,
       Position,
       Title,
       Description,
       Url,
       ScreenID,
       CompanyMask,
       NodeID,
       ParentID,
       CreatedByID,
       CreatedByScreenID,
       CreatedDateTime,
       LastModifiedByID,
       LastModifiedByScreenID,
       LastModifiedDateTime,
       RecordSourceID
FROM dbo.SiteMap
WHERE ScreenID Like 'AU%'
      AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.PortalMap
    WHERE CompanyID = dbo.SiteMap.CompanyID
          AND ScreenID = dbo.SiteMap.ScreenID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and @Kurt Bauer answer is the correct answer but I needed to update the SQL to get mine to work (version 18.212) and the sql is to big for a comment. I found that inserting for the company I was in did it for me, not just CompanyID 1. Here is the SQL I used:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PortalMap
(
    CompanyID,
    Position,
    Title,
    Description,
    Url,
    Expanded,
    IsFolder,
    ScreenID,
    CompanyMask,
    NodeID,
    ParentID,
    CreatedByID,
    CreatedByScreenID,
    CreatedDateTime,
    LastModifiedByID,
    LastModifiedByScreenID,
    LastModifiedDateTime,
    RecordSourceID
)
SELECT CompanyID,
       Position,
       Title,
       Description,
       Url,
       Expanded,
       IsFolder,
       ScreenID,
       CompanyMask,
       NodeID,
       ParentID,
       CreatedByID,
       CreatedByScreenID,
       CreatedDateTime,
       LastModifiedByID,
       LastModifiedByScreenID,
       LastModifiedDateTime,
       RecordSourceID
FROM dbo.SiteMap
WHERE ScreenID = 'AU000000'
      AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.PortalMap
    WHERE CompanyID = dbo.SiteMap.CompanyID
          AND ScreenID = dbo.SiteMap.ScreenID
);
```

Comment: I have this issue after restoring a client's db backup, but this script didn't help.  In fact, i had to remove the sitemap row it created to even run the site without a runtime error.  Anyone solve this differently? I can't modify my customizations.

Comment: For 2019 R2, this resolved my issue once I removed references to the columns "Expanded" and "IsFolder".