# You have insufficient rights to access the object Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

```
I had fixed this bug. When I create new I had check to Create Portal, so that is my problem, maybe in new version it doesn't need create portal check.
```

I got trouble when I try to Open Project MyCustomize of me to customize a project I had setup by Acumatica setup 2017 R2

Any ideas for this?

[image]

Comment: Check your user's access rights for Customization Browser

Comment: I had check all access right tab, nothing wrong :(

Comment: It seems like you have installed Customer Portal and not the ERP. May be it is the reason that you're not able to open Customization Browser

Comment: Yes, when I setting this. I had choose Create Portal. My friend choose it too and he don't see this exception like me. He can work with it.
I will try create with no portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues when upgrading the portal to 2017 R2 and 2018 R1.  Basically the customization browser page is missing from the site map.  See the link below for the SQL code to update the table.

[Cannot Customize using customize browser on portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997698/cannot-customize-using-customize-browser-on-portal)