# Can't edit/open a customization after restoring a client db

Tags: acumatica

I'm having the same symptoms that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997698/cannot-customize-using-customize-browser-on-portal) mentions, but the suggested resolution didn't work. After I restored a client db locally to work with their data and debug a customization, I can no longer open/edit the customization by clicking on the customization in Acumatica. An error displays that "You have insufficient rights to access the object (ProjectBrowserMaint)". The user has customization access, so I'm assuming the problem has something to do with the Acumatica bug mentioned in the post I linked above when Portal is also installed.  The suggested SQL change did not help. Does anyone else have another solution or SQL script that might help? We can't open/edit a customization right now.

Answer (score 0):

When the above happened on our side, we;

1. Checked the admin role to ensure it does not inherit role access from another on a lower level.
2. Then we created a new user that is linked to administrator role only.

This solved the issue for us.