# Customisation Project Browser Permission Issue

Tags: acumatica

So I'm trying to do portal customisation. I've managed to sort out the [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997698/cannot-customize-using-customize-browser-on-portal) with ProjectBrowserMaint. But when loading the customisation page. It's missing the tree items on the left side. I reckon its another access issue.

[image]

So I've explicitly configured the Access Rights on all the screens under the Customisation Project Browser. But still no joy.

[image]

So what else am I missing ? My login has an Administrator and Customiser roles already. And I'm using 2020 R1 Build 20.108.0019.

TIA

Comment: I've experienced some quirky stuff in customizing. A couple things to try would be to force a page recache (refresh the page while holding shift) and unpublish and republish. This often fixes odd quirks.

Comment: i know what you mean @Deetz. Have refreshed and restarted a few times. But I don't think that's it.